# Undesired result using eval on divide

Tags: python-2.7

The code

> eval("7/2")

yields the result `3`. I would prefer that it returned `3.5`. How can I achieve this please?

Update: I have now realised that the eval() is a 'red herring' and this is a duplicate of [How can I force division to be floating point? Division keeps rounding down to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267869/how-can-i-force-division-to-be-floating-point-in-python) and probably about a hundred other questions.

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: @Wooble to evaluate a postfix expression after converting it back to infix notation. If you can point me to a Python algorithm for evaluating postfix notation I could probably get rid of it. What is wrong with eval? It appears from the answers received that the eval is a red herring in this problem anyway and the integer result is the natural effect of dividing two integers in Python 2.

Comment: Postfix arithmetic is really simple to evaluate with a stack, assuming you can tokenize the values and operators first. Go through the sequence of tokens one by one. If a token is a value, push it onto the stack. If a token is an operator, pop the appropriate number of values (e.g. 2, for a binary operator) off the stack and run the operator on them, then push the result back on. Wikipedia [describes the algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation#Postfix_algorithm) pretty well.

Comment: @Blckknght the input is helpfully already tokenized. I've just started writing my own variation of http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866502/470014 which seems to be a pretty good algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, the result of dividing two integers is an integer:

```
In [1]: 7/2
Out[1]: 3
```

If you introduce a floating point number, the result is a floating-point number:

```
In [2]: 7/2.0
Out[2]: 3.5
```

In Python 3, dividing integers yields floats, see [PEP 238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

You can achieve the same behaviour in Python 2 like this:

```
In [3]: from __future__ import division

In [4]: 7/2
Out[4]: 3.5
```

And to perform integer division:

```
In [5]: 7//2
Out[5]: 3
```

Comment: I assumed it was a side-effect of the eval() but I can see what's going on now, thanks. Looks like a good reason for me to upgrade to Python 3 otherwise it's going to be difficult and a bit messy to code what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Is there a way I can force operator.div to return a float as well?

Comment: @Caltor: I don't believe so, but you could use [`operator.truediv()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.truediv) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Python is dynamically typed, and you're passing it integers implicitly by leaving off the decimal.

Just use either 7.0/2 or 7/2.0.

This will let python know that you're using floating points.

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 divides based on the types of input variables. To get the desired result, you either:

- "Transform" one of the variables into float-point `7/2.0` or `7.0/2`; or
- Import the division feature from the future implementation package:

  `In[1]: from __future__ import division`

Then do the division like you're doing:

```
In[2]: 7/2
Out[2]: 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c 'print eval("float(7)/float(2)")'
```

Comment: I appreciate the implication to use the float() function here. Not sure why someone has downvoted it. Maybe the answer is a bit terse for their liking.